# How can I run Visual Studio without elevated access

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-10, uac

I want to debug a program inside Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 10.

I want Visual Studio to be running as a normal user, as I am trying to find areas in the code that fail with standard permissions.

As a standard user, when I try to run devenv.exe I always get prompted for elevated access, which is precisely what I do not want.

I tried putting my standard user in the debugger user group, and it made no difference.

Comment: Can you use VS 2017?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend compiling your code and trying to run the compiled application outside of the IDE. Making sure that your application manifest settings are of the lowest privilege.